# Sharepoint Central Admin not opening on default url

Tags: central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem

I've installed sharepoint on my windows pc. When I try to open central admin using Windows key and run as administrator, browser opens correctly. Even, url is shown correctly, but nothing show up there.
Here I've attached screenshot for it
[image]

But, If I append applications.aspx after, it shows central admin correctly.[image]

It was working correctly before, Today I don't know why is not working correctly.
Is there any setting, where we need to specify default url for applications.aspx?

Comment: have you tried with /default.aspx appended to the end of the URL?

Comment: yes. it shows same error.

Comment: Open Regedit. HKLM > Microsoft > Shared Tools > Web Server Extensions > 15 > WSS > CentralAdminURL. What does it say?

Comment: There isn't any HKLM in Regedit. There are all from HKEY.

Comment: I know it is long time, but can you let me know what is the resolution of this issue. I am currently facing it.